# Alarm is setting 12 hours later in my Alarm android app whenever the time is 12:xx PM

Tags: android

I a building an alarm app in android. But whenever the time is 12 in noon. it automatically set the alarm 12 hours later. like If I am setting the alarm at 10:00 it is then setting it to 22:00. And If I am setting the alarm at 14:00 it is setting the alarm at 02:00 the next day. 
This error is only happening when my android clock says 12.xx.

I am taking the time and date from a button text..
Here is the code and the log.

```
Date today = c.getTime();

                setAlarmTimeAndDate = Calendar.getInstance();
                setAlarmTimeAndDate.set(Calendar.DATE, Integer.parseInt(saveDateButton.getText().toString().substring(0, 2)));
                setAlarmTimeAndDate.set(Calendar.MONTH, Integer.parseInt(saveDateButton.getText().toString().substring(3, 5)) - 1);
                setAlarmTimeAndDate.set(Calendar.YEAR, Integer.parseInt(saveDateButton.getText().toString().substring(6, 10)));
                setAlarmTimeAndDate.set(Calendar.HOUR, Integer.parseInt(saveTimeButton.getText().toString().substring(0, 2)));
                setAlarmTimeAndDate.set(Calendar.MINUTE, Integer.parseInt(saveTimeButton.getText().toString().substring(3, 5)));

                Log.d("currentDateAndTime", c.getTime().toString());
                Log.d("ButtonDateAndTime|alarm", saveDateButton.getText().toString()
                        + "|" + saveTimeButton.getText().toString()
                        + "|" +setAlarmTimeAndDate.getTime().toString());
```

logs:

```
    03-12 02:31:39.814 6896-6896/com.codedweeb.notesandmemo D/currentDateAndTime: Sun Mar 12 02:31:28 GMT+05:30 2017
03-12 02:31:39.814 6896-6896/com.codedweeb.notesandmemo D/ButtonDateAndTime|alarm: 12/03/2017|03:30 AM|Sun Mar 12 03:30:39 GMT+05:30 2017

    03-12 12:33:20.366 6896-6896/com.codedweeb.notesandmemo D/currentDateAndTime: Sun Mar 12 12:33:18 GMT+05:30 2017
03-12 12:33:20.366 6896-6896/com.codedweeb.notesandmemo D/ButtonDateAndTime|alarm: 12/03/2017|03:30 AM|Sun Mar 12 15:30:20 GMT+05:30 2017
```

I changed the time of my phone and then it put alarm 12 hours late.

Comment: Please format your code properly. What is `Date today` for?

Comment: Date today is a Date variable and c is the instance of Calendar with current Date and time.
this is used to see if user is setting alarm in the past or not.
so, today is the value of the Date and time on which user is setting the alarm. @BasilBourque

Comment: I don't understand the question TBH.

Comment: What I am doing here is setting an alarm in android by taking time and date from a string.
Suppose I gave you a string in DD/MM/YYYY and HH/MM. Now you have to set an alarm using these two. How would you do that ?
I am taking those string from a button text(saveDateButton and saveTimeButton) and trying to set an alarm using variable setAlarmTimeAndDate which is an instance of Calendar.

Comment: Before setting the alarm I print in the logs the value of variable setAlarmTimeAndDate.getTime().toString() to check. I have given the log results

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY instead of Calendar.HOUR.  You must be facing this issue from 12 to 24 hour of day. Calendar.HOUR is used for 12 hour clock system, while Calender.HOUR_OF_DAY is used for 24 hour clock system.

When new instance of Calendar object been cleated after 12 hour,time was in PM(after 12), you tried to set Calender.HOUR as 3, so it's making it 3 PM, mean 15 hour.

Comment: you saved my day sir. Thanks a lot.
I will be keep checking and inform you if any error will come. 
Currently, I tested every possible combination of time I can think of.

Answer (score 0):

There's a straightforward calculation based on hour to determine AM vs. PM and return the time as a text string. Here's the code:

```
timeString="";
int hour = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
if (hour == 0) {
   timeString =  "12AM (Midnight)";  
} else if (hour < 12) {
   timeString = hour +"AM";
} else if (hour == 12) {
  timeString = "12PM (Noon)";
} else {
  timeString = hour-12 +"PM";
}
```

Comment: I already applied this, but somehow someway in android it was not working correctly. Although I tested my Java method on Java compiler, It was working fine. I don't know maybe a bug. But the above solution is fine and solved my problem. Thanks for the answer.